# Calling Tkinter element by grid position

Tags: python, tkinter, grid

I'm working on an interface that needs me to highlight labels in a grid corresponding to butte inputs in a separate panel, for this i was hoping to use a "map" consisting of a matrix of 0's and 1's matching the grid of my program, and then using that map to change the color of the corresponding labels in the map. For this to work I would have to be able to call a label not by its name but its grid position for the config function, is there a way to do that.

Thanks in advance for considering my problem.

```
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()
val_x = 20
val_y = 20

label_tl = Label(root, text="1", padx=val_x, pady=val_y)
label_tr = Label(root, text="2", padx=val_x, pady=val_y)
label_bl = Label(root, text="3", padx=val_x, pady=val_y)
label_br = Label(root, text="4", padx=val_x, pady=val_y)

label_tl.grid(row=0, column=0)
label_tr.grid(row=0, column=1)
label_bl.grid(row=1, column=0)
label_br.grid(row=1, column=1)

map_one = [[0, 0], [1, 0]]

for x in map_one:
    for y in x:
        if y == 0:
            grid[x, y].config(bg="white")
        else
            grid[x,y].config(bg="blue")

root.mainloop()
```

This is the code as i wanted it, though the grid[x, y] is not a real funktion and im looking for something that does the same.

Comment: edit the question and add the ready code you wrote

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Typo error missing colon.  else should be else:   line 23, in <module>
    rid[x, y].config(bg="white")
NameError: name 'rid' is not defined. Did you mean: 'Grid'?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like homework?
By coincidence the son of a friend had exactly this question for me. We ended up with an object oriented solution.

So probably not the answer to your question based on the bit of code you provided, but maybe it helps.

```
import random
import tkinter as tk
from dataclasses import dataclass


class Grid:
    PADX = 40
    PADY = 40
    COLOR_ENABLED = 'teal'
    COLOR_DISABLED = 'white'

    def __init__(self, tk_root, grid_size):
        self.grid_size = grid_size
        self.root = tk_root
        self.root.configure(bg=self.COLOR_DISABLED)
        self.data = []
        counter = 1
        for y in range(self.grid_size):
            for x in range(self.grid_size):
                label = tk.Label(self.root,
                                 text=counter,
                                 padx=self.PADX,
                                 pady=self.PADY,
                                 bg=self.COLOR_DISABLED)
                label.grid(row=y, column=x)
                self.data.append(Field(self, x=x, y=y, widget=label))
                counter += 1

    def set_active(self, x, y):
        for field in self.data:
            field.switch_active(x, y)


@dataclass
class Field:
    parent: Grid
    x: int
    y: int
    widget: tk.Label
    active: bool = False

    def _update_color(self):
        color = self.parent.COLOR_ENABLED if self.active else self.parent.COLOR_DISABLED
        self.widget.configure(bg=color)

    def switch_active(self, x, y):
        self.active = True if self.x == x and self.y == y else False
        self._update_color()


root = tk.Tk()
grid = Grid(root, grid_size=6)


def grid_highlight_test():
    """
    highlights a random label on the grid, loops forever
    """
    random_x = random.randint(0, grid.grid_size - 1)
    random_y = random.randint(0, grid.grid_size - 1)
    grid.set_active(
        x=random_x,
        y=random_y
    )
    print(f'Coordinates X: {random_x} | Y: {random_y}')
    root.after(500, grid_highlight_test)


grid_highlight_test()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `root.grid_slaves(row=..., column=...)` to get the label widget for the specified row and column:

```py
for row, x in enumerate(map_one):
    for col, y in enumerate(x):
        # get the label at (row, col)
        # note that the result of grid_slaves(...) is a list/tuple
        lbl = root.grid_slaves(row=row, column=col)[0]
        lbl.config(bg=("white" if y == 0 else "blue"))
```